# how to convert multi-line json array into php object array to access the properties of that array

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a Json multi-line array sent from AJAX response (Blade to Controller) and Again I am passing that array to a partial view.

How can I access all properties of this array in laravel blade view ?

I tried but in vain:

```
(object)$array "-AND-" json_decode($array, true)
```

This is the JSON array that I am getting on laravel blade view:

```
[{ "id": 1, "name": "Water", "type": "amenity", "active": 1, "created": "2019-03-15 01:09:01", "pivot": { "property_type_id": 3, "amenity_id": 1 } }, 
 { "id": 2, "name": "Electricity", "type": "amenity", "active": 1,
"created": "2019-03-15 00:44:02", "pivot": { "property_type_id": 3, "amenity_id": 2 } }, 
 { "id": 3, "name": "Sui-Gas", "type": "amenity", "active": 1, "created": "2019-03-15 00:44:02", "pivot": { "property_type_id": 3,
"amenity_id": 3 } }, 
 { "id": 4, "name": "Telephone", "type": "amenity", "active": 1, "created": "2019-03-15 00:58:59", "pivot": { "property_type_id": 3, "amenity_id": 4 } }, 
 { "id": 5, "name": "Lawn \/ Garden", "type":
"moreAmenity", "active": 1, "created": "2019-03-15 01:17:58", "pivot": { "property_type_id": 3, "amenity_id": 5 } }, 
 { "id": 6, "name": "Store Room", "type": "moreAmenity", "active": 1, "created": "2019-03-15 01:17:35",
"pivot": { "property_type_id": 3, "amenity_id": 6 } }, 
 {"id": 7, "name": "Laundry Area", "type": "moreAmenity", "active": 1, "created": "2019-03-15 01:17:35", "pivot": { "property_type_id": 3, "amenity_id": 7 } }, 
 {"id": 8, "name": "Garage \/ Parking", "type": "moreAmenity", "active": 1, "created": "2019-03-15 01:18:45", "pivot": { "property_type_id": 3, "amenity_id": 8 } }]
```

I want to access every property of this array either by converting or decoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send JSON data to your view like this:

```
view('view-name')->with('data', json_decode($array, true));
```

See [Laravel Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views)

and in your view, use it like this:

```
@foreach($data as $value)
    ID: {{ $value['id'] }}
    Name: {{ $value['name'] }}
    // .. and so on ..
@endforeach
```

See [Laravel Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates)

Answer (score 0):

First, what do you mean by "multiline json"? if the string is a valid json (no matter what is the content), you can use the built in *json_decode* function to convert your json string into array or object and then, pass the array/object to the view:

```
$jsonString = '[{"id":1,"name":"Water","type":"amenity","active":1,"created":"2019-03-15 01:09:01","pivot":{"property_type_id":3,"amenity_id":1}},{"id":2,"name":"Electricity","type":"amenity","active":1,"created":"2019-03-15 00:44:02","pivot":{"property_type_id":3,"amenity_id":2}},{"id":3,"name":"Sui-Gas","type":"amenity","active":1,"created":"2019-03-15 00:44:02","pivot":{"property_type_id":3,"amenity_id":3}},{"id":4,"name":"Telephone","type":"amenity","active":1,"created":"2019-03-15 00:58:59","pivot":{"property_type_id":3,"amenity_id":4}},{"id":5,"name":"Lawn \/ Garden","type":"moreAmenity","active":1,"created":"2019-03-15 01:17:58","pivot":{"property_type_id":3,"amenity_id":5}},{"id":6,"name":"Store Room","type":"moreAmenity","active":1,"created":"2019-03-15 01:17:35","pivot":{"property_type_id":3,"amenity_id":6}},{"id":7,"name":"Laundry Area","type":"moreAmenity","active":1,"created":"2019-03-15 01:17:35","pivot":{"property_type_id":3,"amenity_id":7}},{"id":8,"name":"Garage \/ Parking","type":"moreAmenity","active":1,"created":"2019-03-15 01:18:45","pivot":{"property_type_id":3,"amenity_id":8}}]';
$objects = json_decode($json);
//Or alternatively: $array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then you can pass the result into the view (and its subviews of course):

```
return vew('some-view')->with(['objects'=>$objects]);
```

And using the for or foreach insruction in the view:

```
@foreach($objects as $object)
$object->id <br/> $object->name <br/> $object->pivot->property_type_id
@endforeach
```

Comment: Really Thankful to You Alsoo. You did the object array approach I have implemented your approach.